# Canadian Citizens residing in the US on an E2 business visa wanting to travel to Canada to visit sick and elderly parents and children

Tags: usa, canada, covid-19

My wife and I are Canadian citizens residing in USA on an E2 business/investor non-immigrant visa. We have a home in Toronto Canada as well as close family there (elderly and frail 92 yrs old mother, children and grand children). We are planning to travel to Canada to visit and spend time with my mother and our children. We have a home where upon arrival, we can be safely quarrantined for 14 days.
Will we be allowed to cross the border into Canada?

Answer (score 8):

These are [the rules for Canadians *without Covid symptoms* returning to Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/publications/diseases-conditions/2019-novel-coronavirus-information-sheet.html) as of August 2020.

> You MUST quarantine for 14 days, provide contact information and
> monitor yourself for symptoms subject to the Minimizing the Risk of
> Exposure to COVID-19 in Canada Order (Mandatory Isolation) No. 3.
>
> Ensure you have a suitable place of quarantine that has the
> necessities of life. Go directly to your place of quarantine without
> delay and stay there for 14 days from the date you arrived in Canada.
> You must wear a suitable mask or face covering while in transit.
> Practise physical distancing at all times.

**Note that [quarantine means not having contact with anyone outside your household](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/publications/diseases-conditions/coronavirus-disease-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-home-exposed-no-symptoms.html).** (your household being people you live with, i.e. you and your wife). **So you need to spend 14 days in quarantine in your home before you visit (or are visited by) your close friends and family.** You would want to do this anyway because your 92 year old mother is exceptionally vulnerable to Covid.

You need to convince border guards that you have a plan to achieve this and will follow. While Canadian citizens will not be denied entry, you should be aware that failure to quarantine is punishable by a $750,000 fine and/or six months in prison.

Comment: "You need to convince border guards that you have a plan to achieve this and will follow it before they allow you in." Canadian citizens cannot be denied entry to Canada no matter what. In the worst case, they might be forcibly quarantined, but they still have to be allowed into the country.